# Faulty tag badge description

Tags: bug, status-completed

[lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep) just received the first [tag badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) for [footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footnotes):

[image: Recent badges]

However, the tag badge description states:

[image: Footnotes badge]

which is clearly not the case; a bronze tag badge is awarded when the user has "Earned **100** upvotes for at least 20 answers in the [footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footnotes) tag".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number for the gold badge slipped into the description of the silver and bronze badges. The next build will fix that. Thanks!